# What does # mean in LISP

Tags: syntax, lisp, common-lisp, special-characters

For example, `#'functionname`, is it necessary?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**#'functionname in Common Lisp**

Common Lisp and some other Lisp dialects have more than one namespace. Here the ones for functions and values are different. To get the *function value* of a name, we need to write:

```
(function functionname)
```

Since that is a bit long to write, there is a shorter notation:

```
#'functionname
```

To show the effect see this:

```
(let ((foo 42))
  (flet ((foo () 'bar))
    (list foo (function foo) #'foo (foo))))
```

Above defines a *local variable* `FOO` and a *local function* `FOO`.
The list statement returns the *value* of `FOO`, then the *function value* of `foo` using the `(function ...)` notation, then the same using the short hand notation and then the value of actually calling the function `FOO`.

`(function foo)` and `#'foo` are the same concept, but written differently. Both refer to the local lexical function named `FOO`. `FOO` is introduced by the `FLET` form as a *local function*.

The Lisp REPL returns something like this:

```
(42 #<function FOO 4060008224> #<function FOO 4060008224> BAR)
```

Above shows that the first item is really the *value* of the variable `FOO` and the next two items are the *function values*, the function bound to `FOO`. The last item is the symbol `BAR`, as returned from the function call `(FOO)`.

This separation of namespaces for normal values and function values is present in Common Lisp, Emacs Lisp and ISLisp. Other Lisp dialects like Scheme don't have that separation. In Scheme a name can only denote one value.

**The # character**.

The `#` character is used to introduce special syntax in s-expressions. Here are some examples:

```
#'functionname   ->  (function functionname)
#(1 2 3)         ->  the vector of the elements 1 2 3
#c(1 2)          ->  a complex number
#xFFFF           ->  a hex number
#b1111           ->  a binary number
```

and many more. `#` is a so-called *dispatching macro character*.

The ANSI Common Lisp HyperSpec describes the `#` character in [Section 2.4.8 Sharpsign](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dh.htm).

Common Lisp could have used a different syntax for vectors. Say `[1 2 3]`. It also could have used a different syntax for complex numbers. Something like `{1 2}`. But it does not do that. Why? The reason is because Common Lisp tries to be economical with character usage in the language and leaves characters like `[`, `]`, `{` and `}` to the user for his/her own syntax extensions. Often Lisp users develop embedded languages and to make that a bit easier, the Common Lisp standard tries to keep character usage down to a minimum and also provides the mechanism of macro characters and dispatch macro characters.

To keep character usage down, a single dispatch character `#` is used and the next character then determines what can be denoted. `#b` for binary numbers. `#x` for hex numbers. `#c` for complex numbers. `#(` for vectors. `#'` for function names. Plus many more.

Since Common Lisp is a programmable programming language, this character level syntax can be changed by the user. See the function [SET-DISPATCH-MACRO-CHARACTER](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set__1.htm#set-dispatch-macro-character).

Comment: you have provided an excellent article!  I found it just when I needed it!