# What does the sequence #' mean in Python source code

Tags: python

In `os.py` there is a strange marker `#'` under the docstring and just before the imports

```
>>> import os
>>> os??
File:        /usr/local/lib/python3.11/os.py
Source:     
r"""OS routines for NT or Posix depending on what system we're on.

This exports:
  - all functions from posix or nt, e.g. unlink, stat, etc.
  - os.path is either posixpath or ntpath
  - os.name is either 'posix' or 'nt'
  - os.curdir is a string representing the current directory (always '.')
  - os.pardir is a string representing the parent directory (always '..')
  - os.sep is the (or a most common) pathname separator ('/' or '\\')
  - os.extsep is the extension separator (always '.')
  - os.altsep is the alternate pathname separator (None or '/')
  - os.pathsep is the component separator used in $PATH etc
  - os.linesep is the line separator in text files ('\r' or '\n' or '\r\n')
  - os.defpath is the default search path for executables
  - os.devnull is the file path of the null device ('/dev/null', etc.)

Programs that import and use 'os' stand a better chance of being
portable between different platforms.  Of course, they must then
only use functions that are defined by all platforms (e.g., unlink
and opendir), and leave all pathname manipulation to os.path
(e.g., split and join).
"""

#'
import abc
import sys
import stat as st

from _collections_abc import _check_methods

GenericAlias = type(list[int])
...
```

Does the #' have some special meaning there? I assume if nobody removed that in over 20 years of eyes on this file that it must be there for a good reason (some macro, or some kind of marker for a text processor, but I could not find what). And, like the `#!`, it is difficult to search for information about.

What is the point of those #' comment?

Comment: No it's a simple comment, it doesn't mean anything except if you have an external tool that use it. If you have a french keyboard this 2 keys are side by side. A typo?

Comment: PEP8 defines "Each line of a block comment starts with a # and a single space"

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the Cpython git history, this was added to os.py under this [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/269b83bc05452f4f54fa9df5a76608f88da544fe): "added several more __all__ lists".

Interestingly, another `#'` was added under the same commit but was later removed without any specific reasoning [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7372b06cd7b6b1e88482215ffa27eec8e4b7861a).

`#'` does not have any special significance in Python. It is used in other languages like [LISP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873810/what-does-mean-in-lisp). This is probably just a typo.